# Does John Stewart have his own comic line in the new-52?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, the-new-52

Growing up on the DCAU, John Stewart was the green lantern. As a child, I honestly didn't know who Hal Jordan was. Because of that, as an adult, my impression of Hal can be summed up as follows.

```
Hal Jordan is a twit.
```

I've been picking up the new 52 series recently, but have been avoiding the green lantern titles because I just dislike Jordan. I've seen Stewart featured in side-roles in other series at the local book store, but I'd be curious to know, does John Stewart have his own series where he is the primary protagonist?

Comment: I agree that John Stewart is awesome, but is there any basis to your "dislike" of Jordan and thinking of him as a "a twit" other than not having grown up with his version of Green Lantern?  If you think of him as a villain rather than a hero due to his "Parallax" phase, I might understand, but I suspect you aren't aware of that....

Comment: @Praxis I just dislike his personality from what I've seen in the new 52 justice league comics and have a hard time believing he could stand on his own as a believable character. That is further tained by the fact that in my mind he is not the *one true* green lantern. These two facts lead me to the above conclusion. =)

Comment: @Sidney - It's worth reading both the Green Lantern title and Green Lantern Corps from Green Lantern Rebirth on. It'll give you a good appreciation for Hal AND give you tons of enjoyable John Stewart.

Comment: @Sidney : Hal was definitely a better character before the New 52.  I think I understand your position now.  You might want to go back and read some of the major events between 1986 and 1999 (there are probably compilations that select the relevant issues).  Hal has an interesting character arc that takes a sudden turn when the Cyborg Superman does something terrible to Coast City (during the *Reign of the Supermen* saga).

Comment: @Sidney : Also, probably unnecessary disclaimer, since I notice you've got a downvote: I did not downvote you (in fact, I just upvoted you, as I had never considered whether John had his own series or not, and I think it's a good question).

Comment: @Praxis No problem, I expected some haters. =P Just 54 more rep and I can see how many DV's I actually get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Green Lantern Corps* features John Stewart and Guy Gardner as the main characters. *[Green Lantern Corps Vol 3](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps_Vol_3_1)* is the first in the series to be part of the New 52.

[image]

Unfortunately, John Stewart is not the lone protagonist of any New 52 comic line.